# Application Insights - Undefined Cloud Role Name with 2.4.0-beta3

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We're trying out the app insights multi role preview as announced here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/app-insights-microservices/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-multi-role-apps#use-cloudrolename-to-separate-components

We've added the 2.4.0-beta3 packages for appinsights & appinsights.windowsserver as the app we're using is hosted on prem (IIS) currently.

Our `cloud_rolename` seems to be undefined in our request telemetry. Is there anything further we need to do other than updating the packages?

We also found this:

`AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer` updates the `RoleName` and `RoleInstance` properties of the Device context for all telemetry items with information extracted from the Azure runtime environment.

..though our `Cloud_RoleInstance` property is being properly populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#telemetry-initializers-aspnet), I had to assign `Cloud.RoleName` using [a custom `ITelemetryInitializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties) to assign `ITelemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName` property which will assign the proper context for a given request when [using multi-component apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-multi-role-apps#use-cloudrolename-to-separate-components).

#### Telemetry Initializer for Multi-Component Apps

```cs
  public class MultiComponentTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry?.Context?.Cloud == null) return;
        requestTelemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "myapp-api";
    }
  }
```

This initializer only works on the server side APIs - I have [not found the equivalent hook for the client JS SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS).

Comment: Where to call the Initialize method in .NET web application either **Global.asax.cs** or **ApplicationInsights.config**. which way is recommended way.

Comment: I'd latch onto `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs` for .NET apps, and during `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup.cs` for .NET Core apps - you need to configure the initializer before requests are processed

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include cloud role instance and name with the app insights js sdk, I had success doing this:

```
appInsights.queue.push(() => {
appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
  envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
  envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role isntance";
});
```

});

Answer (score 4):

In web applications, **Cloud_RoleName** is a value of an environment variable  **WEBSITE_SITE_NAME** which is set automatically when hosted in Azure.
For on-premises you can set this variable manually.
For debugging environment variables can be set in *Project settings > Debug > Environment variables* [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCKp.png).

[Source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/ce6b4caade8566a451b3c98a10bc077d021f494f/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer.cs#L62) of Application insights where **Cloud_RoleName** is retrieved.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `@microsoft/applicationinsights-web` npm package then shorter version would be:

```
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
        instrumentationKey: 'your instrumentation key'
    }
});
appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((telemetryItem) => {
    telemetryItem.tags['ai.cloud.role'] = 'your app name';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add all the relevant appinsights packages. I had the same problem with my Stateless service fabric service. After adding `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric` package `rolename` is added to the telemetry data.

Comment: There are 25 nuget packages and very low documentation about these things

Answer (score 2):

**This was an edit to [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45417851/895167) but it was rejected which is illogical tbh.**

If you want to include cloud role instance and name with the app insights js sdk, I had success doing this:

```
appInsights.queue.push(() => {
    appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
      envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
      envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role isntance";
    });
});
```

You should add this in your layout/master pages with the Application Insights initialization script right before `appInsights.trackPageView();` so it becomes:

```
var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config)
{
    function r(config){ t[config] = function(){ var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function(){ t[config].apply(t, i)})} }
    var t = { config:config},u=document,e=window,o='script',s=u.createElement(o),i,f;for(s.src=config.url||'//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js',u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s),t.cookie=u.cookie,t.queue=[],i=['Event','Exception','Metric','PageView','Trace','Ajax'];i.length;)r('track'+i.pop());return r('setAuthenticatedUserContext'),r('clearAuthenticatedUserContext'),config.disableExceptionTracking||(i='onerror',r('_'+i),f=e[i],e[i]=function(config, r, u, e, o) { var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o); return s !== !0 && t['_' + i](config, r, u, e, o),s}),t
}({
    instrumentationKey:'Instrumentation Key'
});

window.appInsights = appInsights;
appInsights.queue.push(() => {
    appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
      envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
      envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role isntance";
    });
});
appInsights.trackPageView();
```

Source1: [Modifying and Filtering Telemetry with AppInsights JavaScript SDK Telemetry Initializer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/albulank/2016/04/20/modifying-and-filtering-telemetry-with-appinsights-javascript-sdk-telemetry-initializer/)

Source2: [Filtering and preprocessing telemetry in the Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer)

SDK Reference: [addTelemetryInitializer](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#addTelemetryInitializer)