# How to add custom role in Angular TypeScript in Microsoft AppInsights

Tags: angular, typescript, appinsights

I have an angular project which I want to include AppInsight with telemetry (custom role).
The project is written in Angular with TypeScript, I followed this [tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/) to integrate appinsights in the angular project and it seems to work fine. I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=javascript)
to add custom telemetry (with the role) but it's written in Java/JavaScript/Node.JS

When I tried to use the JS code which is

```
this.appInsights.queue.push(() => {
      this.appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
        envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
        envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role instance";
      });
    });
```

I got an error:

```
TS2339: Property 'queue' does not exist on type 'Initialization'.
```

It's probably because it's in JS and not TS.

I also tried to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45417851/12546733) without any success

```
this.appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(envelope => {
  envelope.tags['ai.cloud.role'] = 'your cloud role name';
  envelope.baseData.properties['item'] = 'some property';
});
```

This is the code for my **MonitoringService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../../../environments/environment';
import {ApplicationInsights} from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';

@Injectable()
export class MonitoringService {
  appInsights: ApplicationInsights;

  constructor() {
    this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
        enableAutoRouteTracking: true // option to log all route changes
      }
    });
    this.appInsights.queue.push(() => {
      this.appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
        envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
        envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role instance";
      });
    });
    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
  }

  logPageView(name?: string, url?: string) { // option to call manually
    this.appInsights.trackPageView({
      name: name,
      uri: url
    });
  }

  logEvent(name: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackEvent({name: name}, properties);
  }

  logMetric(name: string, average: number, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackMetric({name: name, average: average}, properties);
  }

  logException(exception: Error, severityLevel?: number) {
    this.appInsights.trackException({exception: exception, severityLevel: severityLevel});
  }

  logTrace(message: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackTrace({message: message}, properties);
  }
}
```

I also tried to update the Microsoft dependency from 2.4.4 to 2.5.10 but it didn't make any change.

When I'm opening AppInsights there is a role but it does not set properly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the exact same issue, but I needed to run the telemetry initializer after loadAppInsigthts, like so:

```
      this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();

      const telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
        envelope.tags['ai.cloud.role'] = 'name-of-your-app';
      };
      this.appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```

(source: https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-js#example-setting-cloud-role-name)

Does that make any difference?

(I'm using version 2.5.9)